# select table record in database by multi id by php

Tags: php, database, select

i have a value that name is brands and like this :

```
$brands = "1,2,3,4,5,";
```

i can convert this value to this :

```
$brands = "1,2,3,4,5";
```

i want write source that select * from table where id = each of brands

for example :

```
select * from brands where (id='1' or id='2' or id='3' or id='4' or id='5');
```

1,2,3,4,5 is Variable and can changed for example can change to 1,2,9,4,5,8

how i can write this ?
please help thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already have the ids comma delimited...

```
$query = '
   SELECT *
     FROM `brands`
    WHERE `id` IN (' . $brands . ')';
```

If not, use `implode(',', $ids)`.

If your ids are from user input and not already made safe, use...

```
$ids = implode(',', array_map('intval', explode(',', $ids)));
```

Answer (score 2):

`"select * from brands where id in (".$brands.");"`